# How do I state a reduction in cost?

Tags: definition, experimental-mathematics, measurement-theory

I have developed an algorithm and am having a hard time stating its benefit versus a baseline.

Suppose that the baseline cost of solving the problem is 1000 seconds. Now suppose that my algorithm reduces the cost to 250 seconds. How do I state that improvement **validly** and **convincingly**?

A. My algorithm reduces the running time by (1000-250)/1000 = 75%.

B. My algorithm improves the running time by (1000-250)/1000 = 75%.

C. My algorithm reduces the running time by a factor of 1000/250 = 4x.

D. My algorithm produces a running time that is 250/1000 = 25% of the baseline.

Comment: I think $A$ and $C$ are both valid and convincing.